# REG QUERY and accented characters in Windows XP

Tags: batch-file, registry, windows-xp

I cannot access to path strings that I query from the registry in Windows XP command line if they contain accented characters.

```
for /f "tokens=4*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Common Start Menu" ^| find /i "Common Start Menu"') do set test=%b
echo %test%
```

In Spanish OS, this code is returning:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Men· Inicio
```

Where "·" should be an "ú", so I can't work with that path, for example if I try to change actual directory to it...

```
cd %test%
```

I end up getting a "the system cannot find the path specified" error. I tried switching between code pages (chcp) but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code snippet:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
MODE CON CP SELECT=1250 > NUL
for /f "tokens=4*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Common Start Menu" ^| find /i "Common Start Menu"') do set test=%%b
MODE CON CP SELECT=852 > NUL
set xest=!test:%%allusersprofile%%=%allusersprofile%!
@echo "%xest%"
@dir /AD "%xest%"
endlocal
```

As I'm on Czech windows, you should modify code pages in both the `MODE CON CP SELECT=xxx` commands to your locale. For your information: 1250=Windows ANSI Central Europe, 852=OEM Central Europe; I guess your ones could be [1252 (ANSI Latin 1; Western European for Windows) and 850 (OEM Multilingual Latin 1; Western European for DOS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The command prompt works in ANSI. Maybe setting it to unicode may help.

```
cmd /u /k <commandname>
```

From Help

Console Code Pages
A code page is a mapping of 256 character codes to individual characters. Different code pages include different special characters, typically customized for a language or a group of languages.

Associated with each console are two code pages: one for input and one for output. A console uses its input code page to translate keyboard input into the corresponding character value. It uses its output code page to translate the character values written by the various output functions into the images displayed in the console window. An application can use the SetConsoleCP and GetConsoleCP functions to set and retrieve a console's input code pages and the SetConsoleOutputCP and GetConsoleOutputCP functions to set and retrieve its output code pages.

The identifiers of the code pages available on the local computer are stored in the registry under the following key.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage

Use command

```
chcp <codepage>
```

or

```
mode cp <codepage>
```

Although 850 (International English is also West European).

Make sure locale is set correctly in Regioanal Optons. Also check setting for non uni

Comment: The command prompt works in OEM, not in ANSI... And the Windows CMD shell does not support Unicode; `CMD /A` or `CMD /U` causes _output only_ in ANSI or UNICODE characters: these options will affect _piping_ or _redirecting_ to a file.